# AWS Pear Package Not working for Macports php56

Tags: php, amazon-s3, macports

I have recently upgraded to Yosemite and have installed php-56. I am running into the problem where I can no longer use Amazon's pear packages. So far I have done this:

```
sudo port install pear-PEAR
sudo port install pear-AWSSDKforPHP
```

And I have the following php code:

```
require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar';

use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
```

And I get the following errors:

```
require_once(AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing for this installation?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

If you don't already have this file, create `'/opt/local/etc/php56/php.ini'` . The easy way to create it is to copy the `/opt/local/etc/php56/php-production.ini` or `/opt/local/etc/php56/php-production.ini` that is already in the the directory.

Step 2

Add this line to the end of your php.ini

```
include_path = ".:/opt/local/lib/php"
```

That will include all the pear libraries